# setHeight() in jfx set height in which unit

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

In Java FX we set the (height/width) of a `Stage` as 
`stage.setHeight()` and `stage.setWidth()`. If for example I wrote :  `setHeight(1000)` would the 1000 be measured in **Pixel** ?

Comment: Yes as for all the other nodes in JavaFX!

Answer (score 0):

Yes 1000 is measured in pixels, though it does not explicitly say this in the documentation I can say that this is true from past experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the *(width, height, x, y)* of your window in several ways and all this is done **in pixels** as explained in the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) **Coordinate System** and **Transformations**. The stage is the main element of a window, so you can assign a size to it through root:

```
scene = new Scene(root,1000,1000);
```

Or directly by calling

```
stage.setHeight(1000);
stage.setWidth(1000);
```

Good luck !